# socket programming using python to connect raspberry pi and windows PC

Tags: python, networking, raspberry-pi

I want to send and receive data between raspberry pi and windows PC. If I placed both server and client program on raspberry pi then it works fine. but when client is run from windows pc then it shows an error 'no connection could be made because the target machine actively refuse it'. I am simply connecting pc and pi through a LAN cable. and firewall of my PC is disabled.

server.py

```
import socket
s=socket.socket()
host=socket.gethostname()
port=12345
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(5)
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print 'got connection from',addr
    c.send('Thank you for connecting')
    c.close()
```

client.py

```
import socket               

s = socket.socket()        
host = '192.168.0.3'# ip of raspberry pi 
port = 12345               
s.connect((host, port))
print s.recv(1024)
s.close()
```

Comment: Is it a crossover cable?

Comment: yes it is a crossover cable.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on the loopback interface (both scripts on the Raspberry Pi), this means your code is correct.

Why it doesn't work over the network is not really programming related. A few things to check:

- As Akash Nil noted, check if you're using a crossover cable. Does the little LED on your LAN port light up when you connect the cable?
- Does `ping` work?
- The RPi doesn't have any firewalling active, either, right?
- If you're using Windows, put the server on the RPi or be 100% sure you've whitelisted Python in your firewall (or deactivated it).
- Does it work if you use [netcat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat) as client or as server?