# Raspberry Pi unable to connect to Windows Websocket

Tags: python, java, websocket, raspberry-pi, micronaut

I am attempting to send data from a Python script running on a Raspberry Pi to a Java Micronaut ServerWebSocket running on a Windows machine, but I am getting `asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError` errors during the process.

I attempted to use the `websockets` library in Python on the Raspberry Pi to establish a websocket connection, but encountered a `ConnectionRefusedError`. Is this issue related to a network problem as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29789333/20561010), and should I ask somewhere else like Superuser or Serverfault? Or is there another solution to this problem?

Comment: What happens if you run your python code on the same machine as the server? If it works than chances are it is a network problem.

Comment: Can you clarify what you've tried to do to troubleshoot so far?

Comment: @DanielCazares I tried Federicos suggestion before asking this queston, and it worked.
I made sure that everything isn't connected to "localhost", but to the IP-Adress of my host machine instead

Comment: @Franz M, On Windows, try to Temporarily turn off Windows Firewall. `Settings` -> `Network & Internet` -> `Status` -> `Windows Firewall` ->  `Public network`
-> `Windows Defender Firewall` (`ON` -> `Off`). This is to clarify whether the connection is refused because of Windows Firewall?

Comment: @life888888 Turned off the public network firewall, still didn't work

Comment: @Franz M, Can you execute your Python script on Windows to connect to Java Micronaut ServerWebSocket on the same machine?

Comment: @life888888 I did execute the Python script on Windows before asking this question and it worked.
My problem is, is that the code for the client _specifically_ doesn't work on a Raspberry Pi. On Windows, everything is fine and works properly, but the problem start to arise as soon as the Raspberry Pi comes into play.

Something interesting to note is that the Pi can communicate with Windows when I am using a python socket instead of the Micronaut one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [@life888888](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75144737/raspberry-pi-unable-to-connect-to-windows-websocket#comment132607850_75144737) suggested, it had something to do with Windows firewall.

But instead of the public firewall being the problem, it was the one for the domain network instead.